# How to know if a link is a video?

Tags: url, video, mime-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine if a given URL link is a video or image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471638/how-to-determine-if-a-given-url-link-is-a-video-or-image)

I'm building a forum and I want the facebook feature whereby when the user paste a video URL, i can automatically know its a video and display it differently??

Comment: Here is a the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471638/how-to-determine-if-a-given-url-link-is-a-video-or-image

Comment: @Hemant: URL in comments tag usage is following: `[ text ] ( url )` (with no spaces of course)

Comment: Plz, for those who voted down this question, i really don't mind :), but at least tell me what's not good with this question so that in future, i don't make the same mistake, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check it's "mime type".

Answer (score 0):

The way Facebook implemented requires quite a lot of computing power and may not be suitable for small scaled website.

After the user input the video URL, Facebook will proceed to determine if the URL belongs to a known host (such as Youtube, CollegeHumour). If the URL does not belong to a known host, Facebook will proceed to retrieve the page and determine the video parameters from the `<meta>` tags,  according to what Facebook defines them to be.

However to keep things easy for you, maybe your forum can determine that if the URL is from Youtube, you can use Youtube's embed code to display the video.

This does not deal with MIME types, or video files directly. If it is video files, you will still need to proceed to fetch the headers of the video file, and determine what plugin or Flash player should display the video.